# Mysql2 and Sqlite3 in Rails

Tags: ruby-on-rails, sqlite, mysql2

I have a rails application which uses two different types of databases : sqlite3 and mysql2.

I did some searching and managed to get this far, my database.yml file looks like this :

```
development:
  adapter: sqlite3
  database: db/development.sqlite3
  pool: 5
  timeout: 5000


mysql2_development:
  adapter: mysql2
  database: db_name
  username: user_name
  password: pass_word
  host: somehost.net
  port: 3306
  socket: /tmp/mysql.sock
```

I created the following classes in models to access my Mysql2 database:

```
class NewDB < ActiveRecord::Base

  # To change this template use File | Settings | File Templates.
  self.abstract_class = true
  establish_connection "mysql2_#{Rails.env}"
end

class PROJECT < NewDB
end
```

Here PROJECT is table present in the "NewDB" database.

**Problem:**

Is this the right way to do it , Also how do I access them from the controller ?

In my controller I tried this:

```
class NewDBController < ApplicationController

  def index
    @projects=PROJECT.all
  end
end
```

But I get the following error "Mysql2::Error: Table 'newdb.projects' doesn't exist: SHOW FULL FIELDS FROM `projects`"

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Did you run a migration for the other environment?

```
rake db:migrate RAILS_ENV=mysql2_development
```

Also your Project class should be called `Project` instead.
You can use:

```
class Project < NewDB
  set_table_name "PROJECT"
end
```

Comment: I tried running that , It gives me this error 

`rake aborted!
Mysql2::Error: CREATE command denied to user 'user_ro'@'10.0.0.123' for table 'schema_migrations': CREATE TABLE `schema_migrations` (`version` varchar(255) NOT NULL) ENGINE=InnoDB`

Comment: Also, the table name in mysql2 db is "PROJECT" with all caps.

Comment: see edited answer for the table name problem. If the table already exists you don't need to run the migration. If not, you have to login to your mysql and give the user_ro write-rights.

Comment: That actually did it. I did not run `rake db:migrate RAILS_ENV=mysql2_development` but its actually working now. Thanks :)

Comment: Good to hear! Please accept the answer if your problem is solved.